# Formatting problem for a user post?

Tags: support, questions, markdown

There are some cases in which a new user will only post questions. Those will not be in the proper format. If we try to change the contents to the proper coding format and then click the update button, it will show "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" message. So what shall I do for this?

Comment: It is uncommon that there is nothing else to fix in a post without proper formatting.

Comment: Yes , i have faced it many times . Some new users will post only code with out the coding format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always improve the question by fixing typos, grammar, links, formatting (spaces/tabs). Although there are some other tricks which are *not encouraged*:

- By using `<code></code>` instead of backticks
- Padding the question with `&nbsp;` <sup>do as if you didn't read this</sup>

Comment: Like this? http://imgur.com/nmNQsFP

Answer (score 4):

It is very uncommon that there is nothing else to fix in a post without proper formatting.  Salutations/Signatures normally appear in such posts, as do "Help me please", some variation on "Thanks in Advance", and/or lower case "i".  Plus there is usually spelling & grammar mistakes or spaces before punctuation (if there is any punctuation at all).  The point is most often there is *something* to fix in order to get over the 6 character limit.

> Some new users will post only code with out the coding format

If there is nothing in the post except code, then leave a comment for the OP and explain what to edit and what they need to add.  Might even be helpful to link to [markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Without any explanation in the question body, it will likely be downvoted, closed, and deleted - so a comment would be better for the OP in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

There's usually something else you can fix. Can you format code better? Can you delete a "thank you"?

If you absolutely can't change 6 characters, then just leave it; another user, perhaps a 2K user with direct editing privileges, will get it.